# JSON time format to Android time format

Tags: java, android, json

My API gives me this result:

```
{"time":{"Hours":0,"Minutes":0,"Seconds":0,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":0,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0,"TotalHours":0,"TotalMilliseconds":0,"TotalMinutes":0,"TotalSeconds":0}}
```

How can I get  ***hh:mm:ss*** format in Android from this?

Comment: You should provide a better example of possible data (not all 0's)

Comment: get the time in MM and then convert it with simpleformat... or.. you are gettings the hours, minutes and second. parse through the json and create the string.

Answer (score 0):

so....

for example:

```
{"time":{"Hours":12,"Minutes":11,"Seconds":23,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":0,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0,"TotalHours":0,"TotalMilliseconds":0,"TotalMinutes":0,"TotalSeconds":0}}
```

I coded this in eclipse, same thing really as android....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {


    String jsonData = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String line;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/example.json"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonData += line + "\n";
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData).getJSONObject("time");

    int hour = object.getInt("Hours");

    int min = object.getInt("Minutes");

    int sec = object.getInt("Seconds");
    System.out.println(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);

}
```

The result is...

> 12:11:23

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     public void getFormatedDate(JSONObject object){
      try {
        JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("time");
        int hour = object1.getInt("Hour");
        int minute = object1.getInt("Minutes");
        int seconds = object1.getInt("Seconds");
        int milis = object1.getInt("Milliseconds");
        String time = hour+":"+minute+":"+seconds+":"+milis;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that -

```
String yourApiString = "";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourApiString); // Converts your API JSON string to JsonObject

    JSONObject timeObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("time"); // Fetch time object

    int hours = timeObject.optInt("Hours"); // Fetches Hours integer
    int minutes = timeObject.optInt("Minutes"); // Fetches Minutes integer
    int seconds = timeObject.optInt("Seconds"); // Fetches Seconds integer

    String time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds; // Concatenate all values to get hh:mm:ss format

    Log.d(TAG, "Time: " + time); // You will get time in hh:mm:ss

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```